# Jenkins change log when using multiple repositories

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using Jenkins pipeline for job executions and pipeline code is committed to subversion repository and checkout as Jenkins library. So whenever I execute job, it will look for changes at my pipeline code repository and publish the change logs. Changes committed to application source code repository is ignoring because of this reason. Do we have any options to specify which repository change logs should be published at Jenkins?